# Why does this file not exist?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

Please help me. I am going crazy.

Why does

```
Directory.Exists(from)
```

return `false` even though the file exists?

http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/3250/filedoesnotexist.png

Comment: Post the contents of the from variable, and how you are generating it.

Comment: Is it a file, or is it a directory?

Comment: Well, you said you're going crazy. So maybe it really *doesn't* exist, and you're just imagining it does!

Comment: I think you have to give us a bit more ;)

Comment: Can you give an example of what is going in [from] it could be the format of the input that is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Directory.Exists(from)`  check if directory exists, use
[File.Exists(from)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) if you want to check if file exists

Comment: I uploaded a picture. http://imageshack.us/f/442/filedoesnotexist.png/

Comment: Wow that was embarrasing. :D Yes i have to use File.Exists. Thanks.

Comment: yea, everything is right, change in your code Directory.Exists to File.Exists, and it will work, hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `File.Exists` for File. You are using `Directory.Exists` which is for Direcotry.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is vaugue enough, just guess:

you're talking about a `File`, but checking for `Directory`.

Write it like this:

```
File.Exists(from)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or, another guess: the file has an extension, say, "whatever.txt", but you have extensions hidden in your Explorer, so Explorer shows the file as "whatever", but searching for "whatever" fails, since you should be searching for "whatever.txt"?

Edit: oh, I neglected to look at the screenshot. Well, the other answers were right then.